# Thoughts on best method for testing for differences in slopes of lines (time series data)?

Tags: time-series, ancova

I have 4 sets of 50 year data (one value per year for each of the 4 different categories)- and would like to test for differences in the slopes of the lines.   I think ANCOVA is appropriate- though maybe not as these are time series data?  And ...how to do post hoc pairwise comparisons?

The data are estimates of parasite production for each year under 4 different climate scenarios ranging from hot and dry to cold and wet (parasite production is directly dependent on temperature).

Comment: So are your data counts then?

Answer (score 1):

You are presuming the model form i.e. 1 slope ; no level shift ; no arima structure ; no outliers; no parameter changes over time ; no varaince changes over time. Simply form a robust ARIMA model and estimate it globally and then locally (each of the 4 separately). Conduct a Chow Test as described in my answer to [How to compare two time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/how-to-compare-two-time-series/48531#48531)

Comment: hmm, thanks! sas even has a proc arima.  I'll look into the Chow test, haven't seen that before.