# Is there such thing as a 'Time Series Analysis', where it can be determined how statistically different two populations are over time?

Tags: time-series, correlation, statistical-significance

I have two sets of data; male **resident** deer and male **foreign** deer. This data contains the daily average distance of each population to the nearest road, 100m on day 1, 450m on day 2, ..., day 365.

What I want to perform is a statistical test, to determine if these two populations are statistically different over the year. I have been researching Time Series Analysis, and I am having troubles finding out whether this is possible.

I want to know if the deer, resident vs. foreign (within a degree of certainty), behave similarly with respect to their distance to roads.

Does this time series test exist? Is there any good papers I should read to learn more about this?

Anything would help at this point.

Thank you,

H.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically diffferent over the year"?

Comment: Are the resident deer's distance to roads in 2017 statistically different than the foreign deer's distance to roads in 2017?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Comparing two time series statistically?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395027/comparing-two-time-series-statistically/412442#412442) discusses this question when there was three separate time series. It is equally applicable to your case of two time series,